# How to update dynamic options in php form

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

**I want to divide and update dynamic options in input boxes in php form**

Here is the output

```
test1-$11,test2-$23,test3-$12
```

I can add this fields in db just fine.

```
if(!empty($_POST["custom_name"][0])) {       
        foreach($_POST["custom_name"] as $k=>$v) {        

           $priceoptions .=  "" . $_POST["custom_name"][$k] . "-$" . $_POST["custom_value"][$k] . ",";
```

I want to display fields in input boxes and add or update them like this ...............

[image]

Here is the reference code - https://phppot.com/php/php-contact-form-with-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to get your output via php. maybe it will help you

```
<?php 

$color="test1-$11,test2-$23,test3-$12";
$re = '/[a-zA-Z0-9]+-\$[0-9]+/m';
preg_match_all($re, $color, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {
    $value = $value[0]; 
    $label = explode('-',$value)[0]; // get label from string
    $value = explode('-',$value)[1]; // get value from string
    $value = str_replace('$','',$value); // repalce '$'
    ?>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $label?>">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value?>">
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi i tried your code, it only works for last one - test3-$12. Other array content does not display in input boxes. Here is the screenshot - https://prnt.sc/sp49hk

Comment: did you change $str value?  if yes then can tell me what value you set.

Comment: $list = explode(',',$color);// string split by ','
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $label = explode('-',$value)[0]; // get label from string
    $value = explode('-',$value)[1]; // get value from string
    $value = str_replace('$','',$value); // repalce '$'    
}

Comment: <input style="width:49%!important; float:left;" type="text" placeholder="Option name" required class="custom-input-field"
                            value="<?php echo $label?>" name="custom_name[]" />
                            
                        <input style="width:49%!important; float:right;" type="number"
                            placeholder="Price" min="0" step="0.01" required class="custom-input-field float-right"
                           value="<?php echo $value?>" name="custom_value[]" />

Comment: can echo your $color and share it with me, please.

Comment: Its same as output.  test1-$11,test2-$23,test3-$12

Comment: just execute var_dump($color) and share screenshot please.

Comment: i shared my output screenshot also. if both strings are the same then the output should be the same. might be for some reason before 'explode' code your  $color value is modifying. can u var_dump before explode? it will help me to identify the problem.

Comment: I added some var_dump for debugging. please try and share a screenshot
<?php 

$color="test1-$11,test2-$23,test3-$12";
var_dump($color);
$list = explode(',',$str);// string split by ','
var_dump($list);
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $label = explode('-',$value)[0]; // get label from string
    $value = explode('-',$value)[1]; // get value from string
    $value = str_replace('$','',$value); // repalce '$'
    ?>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $label?>">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value?>">
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>

Comment: Hi @site123, I update a code. please try and let me know. this is base on regex.

Comment: values does not show in boxes - https://prnt.sc/sp4lp3 and code https://prnt.sc/sp4m4h

Comment: Its working now. https://prnt.sc/sp4tz9. Just one issue- It breaks the add more button sequence. It adds box before last option instead of bottom. https://prnt.sc/sp4ue7

Comment: i think u add extra div after 2nd input tag

Comment: Thanks for your help Nilesh !

Comment: It's my pleasure. :)